# Why is the 2nd for loop is not running?

Tags: java

```
class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Tournament T = new Tournament();
    Team t = new Team();
    T.getInfo2();
    /*T.display2();
    T.teamObject();*/
    int teams = T.num_team;
    int players;
    Team[] tArr = new Team[teams];
    for (int i = 0; i < teams; i++) {
        tArr[i] = new Team();
        tArr[i].getInfo1();
        players = t.num_players;
        player[] pArr = new player[players];
        for (int j = 0; j < players; j++) {
            pArr[j] = new player();
            pArr[j].getInfo();
        }
    }

}
```

Why is the 2nd for loop not running?
There is no compile time error or run time error.
I am not able to sort out the problem.

Comment: did you set the number of players of team ? What is the default value for it? The inner loop will run only if the number is greater than zero

Comment: `players = t.num_players;` after the execution of  this line, what is the value of `players `.That answer resolves 99% of your problem.

Comment: what is your Team constructor code like?  You are most likely not initializing a team size and it may be defaulting to 0, since you are not explicitly setting a team size in this code.

Comment: Is num_players property of Team class int type ?

Comment: May be your num_players is int type property in Team class and by default It is 0 Before for loop you are not setting that property explicitly.So entering condition of for loop is not satisfy

Comment: Need to print the value of `t.num_players` or `players`, t is never changed in the for loop.

Comment: Have you heard about debugging? Try it its very usefull :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it this way :

```
for (int i = 0; i < teams; i++) {
    tArr[i] = new Team();
    tArr[i].getInfo1();
    players = tArr[i].num_players;    
        //  this way you will loop over the num_players of the new team you created
        //  MAYBE this is the problem
    player[] pArr = new player[players];
    for (int j = 0; j < players; j++) {
        pArr[j] = new player();
        pArr[j].getInfo();
    }
}
```

and please read about Java Code Conventions, not respecting the camelCase style of coding makes it very confusing to read the code, classes should start with capital letter for each word with no spaces, and variables start with small letter for the first word, then each other word starts with a capital letter without spaces .... for example

```
Object object = new Object();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
MyArray myArray = new MyArray[myClass.getArrayLength()];
```

and so on, there is no variable in java named T, and even classes are not preferred to be named so, as T is known to stand for Type in generics, alike E is for Elements

sorry for talking about a subject out of scope, but 50% of my problem with reading your code is because of such simple rules

Answer (score 2):

The second loop is executing as intended. Probably `t.num_players` is zero which is getting assigned to players.